# NLog - Why aren't locked files released once Shutdown is called?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, delete-file

I understand NLog's LogManager.Shutdown() to effectively remove all logging items and stop logging. Programmatically deleting a locked log file after this should work, instead I find that it doesn't get deleted immediately, the file is still locked and only gets unlocked after the process ends.

This is my programmatic config:

```
            var fileTarget = new FileTarget()
            {
                FileName = "logs.txt",
                Layout = <string layout>,
                KeepFileOpen = true,
                ArchiveAboveSize = 50000000,
                ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
                ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.DateAndSequence,
                ArchiveDateFormat = DatePattern
            };

            var asyncFileTarget =
                new NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget, 10000, NLog.Targets.Wrappers.AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Block);
            asyncFileTarget.Name = "async_target";

            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
            config.AddTarget(asyncFileTarget);
            config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, asyncFileTarget);
```

Then if I do,

```
    LogManager.Shutdown(); //logs get flushed and written to the file
    File.Delete("logs.txt"); //Nothing happens, file deletes only after process exits
```

I also tried

```
    LogManager.Configuration = null;
```

which had the same result.

I need to have the KeepFileOpen = true for performance reasons.
How do I get NLog to release locked target files?

Comment: What's the NLog version? What's is logged in the internal log (trace level) - see https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging to enable

Comment: I don't know if this helps.  The docs say (emphasis mine):  "keepFileOpen - Indicates whether to keep log file open instead of opening and closing it on each logging event. Changing this property to true will improve performance a lot, but will also keep the file handle locked. **Consider setting openFileCacheTimeout = 30 when enabling this, as it will allow archive operations and react to log file being deleted.**"

Comment: According to the source code `LogManager.Shutdown` just clears the configuration; it doesn't actually *shut anything down*.  If you still have a reference to `fileTarget`, you can close it manually after telling Nlog to shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that nLog (which i'm unfamiliar with) is running on another thread. I'm not sure how familiar you are with multithreading, but this would mean that the File.Delete(Logs.txt) code could be executed **before** LogManager has had a chance to finish shutting down.

Perhaps try using the await keyword on some async functions? Maybe this will help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async

Alternatively, if nLog has a function/indicator like 'IsBusy' or 'isRunning' - you could always use a while loop (after you've called the shutdown)?

Rough Example:

```
       while (nLog.isBusy)
       {
            // Sleep while we wait for the isBusy status to change
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check NLog's source you could see that a shutdown will close all targets. In the Filetarget that's `CloseTarget`. That will remove the locks in the FileAppenders.

I create a really small example show it works. You could see it [here in Github](https://github.com/304NotModified/NLog-Demo-cases/tree/master/FileLocksAndShutdown). Using NLog 4.6.8.

The demo part:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string fileName = "C:/temp/logs.txt";

    var config = CreateLogConfig(fileName);
    LogManager.Configuration = config;

    Console.WriteLine("Write logs");
    var myLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");
    myLogger.Info("Hi from my logger!");

    LogManager.Flush();// flush to check if really locked. You could disable this and it still works.

    WriteConsoleFileExistsAndLockInfo(fileName);

    Console.WriteLine("Shutdown NLog");
    LogManager.Shutdown(); //logs get flushed and written to the file

    WriteConsoleFileExistsAndLockInfo(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine($"File content: {File.ReadAllText(fileName)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Full path: {new FileInfo(fileName).FullName}");
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting file ...");
    File.Delete(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Deleted file");
    WriteConsoleFileExistsAndLockInfo(fileName);
}
```

The output:

[image]

If it still isn't working at your site, check  [NLog's internal log](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging): `<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">`

Of course it could be another process is locking your file. Maybe antivirus software?

Comment: thank you! I'll try this with Trace on and hopefully find what I'm missing